# What is the difference between "Have I got it right" and "Did I get it right"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect

Let's consider the following questions:

> "**Have I got** it right?"

> "**Did I get** it right?"

What nuances are introduced by the past tense and by the present perfect? These two tenses can't make the same meaning, right? Or can they?

Comment: Pretty much no difference in common usage.

Comment: Why not just ask ***Is it right**?*

Comment: I'd like to understand what nuances are introduced by the past tense and by the present perfect.